# What is the + operator before a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was looking into Raphael JS library but I see this:

```
Animation.prototype.delay = function (delay) {
    var a = new Animation(this.anim, this.ms);
    a.times = this.times;
    a.del = +delay || 0;
    return a;
};
```

What is the + operator before the delay variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It converts a <strike>String</strike> variable to a Number, if possible: `+'21.2'` equals `Number(21.2)`. If the conversion fails, it return `NaN` (that's where `|| 0` kicks in in your example code)

Comment: Wouldn't it had been better if they have made the fail = 0 there?

Answer (score 7):

It is a way to make a variable value to number, if the variable has a number. alternative you can use `Number` function.

Answer (score 0):

It is a **Unary Operator**. It converts/parses numbers from a `string`, `boolean` or even `null` values.

It can:

Parse a number from a string, so +"23" returns 23
Parse +True/+False to 1 or 0 respectively.
even +null would return 0.

You can, of course, perform `Math.*` functions on these above-mentioned returns.

eg.

```js
let str = "25.5";
Math.ceil(+str) // would return 26
```

I hope this helps!